# clicking a marker opening a image next to map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a leaflet map which has lots of markers and what I would like is to open a image next to the map which is linked to certain marker on marker click. All I know that I need javascript/jquery and ajax to make this work.

Here is an example what it could look like: http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/special/local/14th-street-businesses/

Any hints/tips/tutorials appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem: http://franceimage.github.io/leaflet/10/

```
var selectedMarker = false;

var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };

L.geoJson(fi_markers, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);

        marker.on('click', function (e) {
            var feature = e.target.feature;
            var content = '<h3>' + feature.properties.popupContent + '</h3><a href="http://www.franceimage.com/en/places-to-visit/?p=' + feature.properties.id + '">' + feature.properties.thumbnail + '</a>';
            document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = content;

            if(selectedMarker != false) {
                selectedMarker.setStyle({ fillColor: "#ff7800"});
            }
            marker.setStyle({ fillColor: "#000000"});
            selectedMarker = marker;
        });

        return marker;              
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

This a way you can do it (there are plenty others)

In this example:

1. There are no ajax calls (and no jquery either). Data is loaded from a geoJson structure (look at http://franceimage.github.io/leaflet/10/data.geojson)
2. The html content of the popup is created using the properties of the geojson feature
3. I have used CircleMarker so that changing the color is a piece of cake

I hope this will help